# Macro that writes Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build as easy user interface as possible in Excel for people with little to no ability, so that they may use my spreadsheet.

The data I have to look at is a 106 different tables. I want to create a button that when pressed will select and print the table that is associated with that button.

I know how to do this however I was wondering if there was a way to build a macro that will create 106 macros each with a different area selected (the different areas are all the same size and have the same distance between them) so that all I have left to do would be to assign the Macros to buttons.

I don't know if this is possible and if it is possible I don't know if its feasible. I would like to know however if and how it could be done.

Edit: What I really want people to be able to do is for people to see the table they want to print and just click the button directly above it to print it. However since there are so many tables I was hoping that there was an easier way than implementing them one by one.

Many Thanks

Comment: No need for 106 different macros, look into `Application.Caller` so you can use that in your single button code to identify which button was pressed.

Comment: I don't think you need 106 different macros. Just one that will be called with a different area passed to it. I guess some can say that you need 105 calling macros, but they can be as easy as `Sub Call_Area1() call Print_Table(Area1) end sub`

Comment: You also want to avoid [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) where possible.

Comment: If you really want to write code that writes code, you *can* - look into what the VBE Extensibility Library has in store for you. Whether you *should* is another question though.

Comment: That said, your question is *too broad* to be a good fit as it stands: the answer is "yes it can be done, using the VBE Extensibility Library", followed by a tutorial on using the VBIDE API. Reference the VBIDE API, explore it, play with it, then try to make code that writes code, and if/when you're stuck on a *specific* problem, we'll be here to help!

Comment: DRY ([Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) is one of the most important principles in computer programming. Writing essentially the same macro 106 times is repeating yourself on a massive scale. @tigeravatar 's recommendation to use `Application.Caller` sounds like the way to go.

Comment: I have got round the problem by using the fact that Excel names the buttons as Button 1, Button 2 etc then I just reference the name of the button and use the final value in the name to select the right table. So I only ended up using 1 sub.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some broad ideas:

- On a spreadsheet, put a 3-column table that lists the name of the 106 tables, the row each one starts in, and the column it starts in. (Since the tables are the same size, you can come up with quick formulas for the row and column values)
- Instead of 106 buttons, make a drop-down list. Selecting an item from the list will look up the table name and its coordinates.